# Different behavior between CMD and PowerShell ISE when trying to access global variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Here's a very simple PowerShell script that behaves differently when executed from CMD vs when executed via the PowerShell ISE:

```
$computerName = "AG562446"
$computerRole = "AllRoles"

Function initialize() {

    ""
    "From the function initialize()"
    " computerName  = " + $computerName
    " computerRole = " + $computerRole
    ""

    $Global:computerName = "AGBATCHSVR01"
    $Global:computerRole = "Batch"

    ""
    "After local assignment inside initialize()"
    " computerName  = " + $computerName
    " computerRole = " + $computerRole
    ""
}

Function main() {

    initialize

    ""
    " computerName  = " + $computerName
    " computerRole = " + $computerRole
    ""
}

main
```

**When executed via CMD:**

```
C:\> powershell C:\Temp\test.ps1

From the function initialize()
 computerName  = AG562446
 computerRole = AllRoles


After local assignment inside initialize()
 computerName  = AG562446
 computerRole = AllRoles


 computerName  = AG562446
 computerRole = AllRoles

C:\>
```

**When executed from ISE (using <kbd>F5</kbd> *Run*/*Continue command*):**

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> C:\Temp\test.ps1

From the function initialize()
 computerName  = AG562446
 computerRole = AllRoles


After local assignment inside initialize()
 computerName  = AGBATCHSVR01
 computerRole = Batch


 computerName  = AGBATCHSVR01
 computerRole = Batch
```

The "Global:" specifier doesn't seem to have any effect when the script is run via CMD. What am I missing here? How do I modify global variables inside a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really are modifying the global variables.  However when you reference just `$computerName` or `$computerRole`, PowerShell finds the script scoped variable you define at the top of your script *before* the global variable with the same name. That is just how dynamic scoping works in PowerShell.

If you want to read and/or write global variables specifically, always use `$global:<variableName>`.  However using global variables is usually not a great idea.  You have provided default values at the script scope so why not reference them e.g.:

```
$Script:computerName = "AGBATCHSVR01"
$Script:computerRole = "Batch"
```

The reason ISE is acting differently is that when you run by `pressing F5` or starting a debug session, ISE is essentially copying the script to the console line by line so Global variables and Script variables become one and the same.  If you go to the ISE command pane and type:

```
C:\Temp\test.p1 <enter>
```

You will see that this time it behaves like CMD (or PowerShell.exe).